# Combining android packages into single project

Tags: android, package, android-manifest, directory-structure

Friends I have 3 android projects in eclipse say App1, App2, App3 and i want to combine all these into another android project say AppStarter which only has buttons to start the main activity of each of those 3 projects. So how can combine all the files of App1,2,3 under AppStarter and what changes do i have to make in android manifest of each project?

Don't refrain from going into details, I am really confused. Although pointing me to right way is also helpful.

Comment: Try to make the jars of App1,App2 and App3 and add them in AppStarter

Comment: But jars can't store any kind of resource(XMLs, drawables,...) and he will have to recomplile and copy jar to main project every time when he makes some changes in app1,2 or 3. Codes from linked project are copied automatically. He also can use resources in library projects. He only have to write activities from library projects to manifest file in main project as usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to do what you want is to use App1,2 and 3 as Android Library project and link them to your main project. All what you have to do this is [HERE](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject).And [there](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects) you can find something helpful about library project.

It's just few mouse clicks.